# Accessing a siblings children, not the first instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.chevronright', function( event ) {
for (var i=0; i<2; i++){
            var $next =  $(this).siblings('.postlink').find('.post-title').eq(i+1).html();
            $('.row').find('.post-title').eq(i).html($next);
}
```

I have three instances of row, and 3 instances of postlink inside each row, and there is also a chevron in each row. I want it so that when the chevron is clicked, the title from the middle one changes to the left one and the rightmost one changes to the middle one.

What happens is that when i click a chevron in row 2 or row 3, the first row is the one that the actions happen to. It gets the title of the chevron that is the next in line, in the row that I click on but it always happens to the first post-title in the page.  How would I need to refer to the children of the chevrons parent row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit "brute force" and sequence dependent but does that: (verbose for clarity)

```js
//chevron is clicked,
$(document).on('click', '.chevronright', function(event) {
  // get the elements with the class
  var myPostlinks = $(this).parent('.row').find('.postlink');
  //the title from the middle one changes to the left one and the rightmost one changes to the middle one.
  // get reference to middle one
  var middleoneNow = myPostlinks.eq(1).find('.post-title');
  // get reference to left one
  var leftoneNow = myPostlinks.eq(0).find('.post-title');
  // Set right to middle (before we change middle)
  myPostlinks.eq(2).find('.post-title').html(middleoneNow.html());
  // Set middle to left now that right is set
  middleoneNow.html(leftoneNow.html());
});
```

```html
<style>.row{border:solid cyan 2px;}</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <span class="chevronright">chevron right</span>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">left title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">middle title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">right title</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="chevronright">chevron right</span>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">left title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">middle title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">right title</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="chevronright">chevron right</span>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">left title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">middle title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="postlink">
    <span class="post-title">right title</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

For clarity here is an assumption on the markup: (yes it is horrid but demonstrates as here:  https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/vfu10c5k/

Comment: Note that I made some basic assumptions on the "row" markup and thus the siblings and children within that.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I'd need to step down a level everytime instead of putting it all on one long sequence?

Comment: IF you do NOT have `.row` as the immediate parent element, use `.parents('.row')` instead - note that this is all depends on the actual markup for the "row" and thus the child/parent relationships within that which I guess at at this point.

Comment: No your markup is fairly accurate, just there are more elements except the titles but that's not the issue right now. Alright I'll try what you suggested out, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
Whatever.find('.post-title:eq('+(i+1)+')').html()
```